# Unitary matrix whose non-zero elements of column are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Is it possible to generate a Unitary matrix $U$ such that the non-zero elements of a column of $U$ is the same. eg.
$$
U =\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
a_1 & a_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and $a_i$ is complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. However, if $U$ is such a matrix, by considering the diagonals of both sides of $U^\ast U=I$ as well as the equality $\|(1,1,\ldots,1)\|_2=\|(1,1,\ldots,1)U\|_2$, it's obvious that $U$ must be the product of a permutation matrix and a diagonal unitary matrix. In particular, it contains one and only one nonzero element on each column or each row.

Answer (score 1):

To be unitary, we should have $$UU^*=U^*U=I$$
or 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
|a_1|^2 & |a_1|^2 & 0\\ 
|a_1|^2 & |a_1|^2+|a_2|^2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & |a_3|^2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2|a_1|^2 & 0 & 0\\ 
a_1a_2^* & |a_2|^2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & |a_3|^2\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
This implies $a_1=0$. But in such case the first diagonal element is also zero which makes the matrix singular. Hence, $U$ cannot be unitary. Also if $a_1$ is instead in the third row, again the same problem happens.

Comment: Yes it is the case for the given example but my question was whether such a matrix can exist where any non zero element in a given column is the same.